# update_frequency vs publish_frequency (costmap parameters)

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `costmap_common.yaml` file which has `update_frequency` and `publish_frequency` parameters.

What is the significance of these parameters? I looked up [costmap_2d wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) and found the following -

`update_frequency` - The frequency in Hz for the `map` to be updated.

`publish_frequency` - The frequency in Hz for the `map` to be publish display information.

What does `map` in the above definitions refer to? Do they refer to the `costmap` (global or local) or do they refer to the `/map` topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369769/update_frequency-vs-publish_frequency-(costmap-parameters)/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-19**:
the costmap for which the parameters are set.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-19**:
What's the difference between `update_frequency` and `publish_frequency` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Going over to an answer now, instead of comments.

`update_frequency` and `publish_frequency` refer to the costmap for which the parameters are set.

As specified in the wiki, and as you cite yourself:

- `update_frequency` is how fast the costmap should be updated. I.e. how often new sensor data is integrated.
- `publish_frequency` is how fast the costmap is published.

note that for some applications (like `move_base`, e.g.) the costmap does not need to be published at all. As `move_base` accesses it via the API, publishing the costmap is only for visualization purposes. This is why there are two parameters, leaving you the choice to publish it, or not; publish it with very low frequency but integrate sensor data faster, or whatever you prefer.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-28**:
Thank you.